# Invoke-RestMethod: POST Assoc-Array using JSON to WebService (System.Collections.Hashtable)

Tags: powershell

I want to POST an associative array to a web-service.

Therefore I create the array in PowerShell this way:

```
$Data = @{
    "MyProperty" = "bla bla";
    "MyFolder" = @{
        "MySubFolder1" = @{
            "MySubProperty" = "bla bla";
        }
        "MySubFolder2" = @{
            "MySubProperty" = "bla bla";
        }
    }
}
```

I use the following line to POST the data to the web-service:

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Body $Data
```

The point is, that not the whole array is reaching the web-service.
Only the top-level data is received correctly. The nested arrays are not accessible. (System.Collections.Hashtable)
It looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [MyProperty] => bla bla
    [MyFolder] => System.Collections.Hashtable
)
```

I did also try `Invoke-WebRequest` instead of `Invoke-RestMethod` and did play with ConvertTo-JSON, but I was not able to find a clean solution to transfer the data nicely to the web-service.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to send a PSObject to the webservice, using `ConvertTo-JSON` should resolve this: `$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Body ($Data | ConvertTo-JSON)`

Comment: @CraftyB Based on your comment I worked out a solution. I did try this before, but had no luck. Code on webserver-side had to be modified to make it work with `ConvertTo-JSON` too.

Comment: If you post this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$Data` has to be converted to JSON using `ConvertTo-JSON`.

Using the following code-line did the trick:

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Body ( $Data | ConvertTo-JSON -Compress ) -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```